# reactotron failed to create store

Tags: react-native, react-redux

"_reactotronReactNative2.default.createStore is not a function"

When I start react native program, see the above message. Anyone has a clue?

My settings:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "ali-oss": "^4.8.0",
    "feathers": "^2.1.4",
    "feathers-authentication-client": "^0.3.2",
    "feathers-hooks": "^2.0.1",
    "feathers-rest": "^1.7.4",
    "feathers-socketio": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.44.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.15.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^1.12.0",
    "reactotron-redux": "^1.12.0",
    "reactotron-redux-saga": "^1.12.0"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to import the config file before your app file.

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import './ReactotronConfig';

import { App } from './src/app';


AppRegistry.registerComponent('tech_stack', () => App);
```

And use `.use(reactotronRedux())` in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

In your ReactotronConfig.js file, be sure to call **seReactNative()** before using **reactotronRedux()**:

```
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';
import { reactotronRedux } from 'reactotron-redux';

Reactotron
  .configure()
  .useReactNative()
  .use(reactotronRedux())
  .connect()
```